# Haskell stack: extra-deps + local filepath + subdirs?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Here's a `extra-deps` dependency from GitHub that works just fine:

```yaml
extra-deps: 
 - github: haskell/lsp
   commit: 7cc05f3d1249d89af91e82e6aa654bb632045307
   subdirs: 
     - lsp
```

And then I want to try something out. So I forked the repo and place it at `../fork/lsp`:

```yaml
extra-deps: 
 - ../fork/lsp
```

Now I need to specify the `subdirs`. I've tried all kinds of combinations, but this dependency syntax doesn't seem to be very composable.
I have looked everywhere (the Stack doc, GitHub issues, stackoverflow) but I couldn't find an example of how to do this.

Is there a way of specifying a local dependency in `extra-deps` with `subdirs`?

p.s. seriously, the Stack documentation is just terrible

Comment: Can't you just do `../fork/lsp/lsp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't you just do ../fork/lsp/lsp? – [Noughtmare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15207568/noughtmare)

This totally works!

Just treat all subdirs as separate packages.

```yaml
extra-deps: 
 - ../fork/lsp/lsp
```